# Make HTTPS call within Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a call within a firebase function to a locally managed server.  I am not super familiar with node as a development environment so I am not sure what is the issue.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const https = require('http');
exports.testPost = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var options = {
    host: 'localdevserver.edu',
    port: 80,
    path: '/my/endpoint'
  };
  let data = '';

  http.get(options, function(resp){
    resp.on('data', function(chunk){
      //do something with chunk
      data += chunk;
      resp.on('end', console.log("dones"));
    });
  }).on("error", function(e){
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  });
});
```

When I look in the Firebase Functions Log, it says either timeout or no reject defined.

Comment: Start off with returning a string to test that it's actually working. Note that you can deploy functions locally with `firebase serve --only functions` (Quicker to test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With HTTP type functions, you need to send a response to the client in order to terminate the function.  Otherwise it will time out.

```
res.send("OK");
```

Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions) for more details.

Comment: This was indeed part of my problem.    I had will add my final solution to your answer for reference.

Comment: I don't think the code in your proposed edit is going to work the way you exepct because you're sending a response before the other HTTP transaction is complete.  That runs the risk of terminating the function before the async request is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SYNC-REQUEST](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request)

> npm install sync-request

```
var request = require('sync-request');
var res = request('GET', 'http://google.com');
console.log(res.body.toString('utf-8'));
```

the function would be something like this:

```
exports.testPost = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    var request = require('sync-request');
    var res = request('GET', 'http://google.com');
    var res = res.body.toString('utf-8');

   resp.on(res, console.log("dones"));
});
```